# count paths from source to destination in a matrix moving in all 4 directions

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, maze

Say, I have a matrix of size `n*n` and I want to traverse from `0,0` to `n-1,n-1` if I'm allowed to move in all four directions - `right`,`left`,`up` and `down`. How do I find all paths using recursion.

Below is my approach for doing this given you're allowed to move in only 2 directions - `right` and `down`.

```
static int findWays2directions( int[][] a, int i, int j ) {
        if ( i < 0 || j < 0 || i == a.length || j == a[0].length )
            return 0;

        if ( i == a.length - 1 && j == a[0].length - 1 )
            return 1;

        int right = findWays2directions( a, i, j + 1 );
        int down = findWays2directions( a, i + 1, j );
        return right + down;
    }
```

However, when allowed to move in all four directions, this does not work, if I were to add the additional recursive steps to the `left` and `up`. This is due to the fact that cycles are generated, as in going from `0,1` to `0,0` and then back to `0,0` leading to an infinite loop. I have tried to avoid this by maintaining a `visited` two-dimensional array, and returning `0` if already visited. However, I don't think that gives me the correct output since the problem is to count paths, and not just do a traversal.

```
static int findWays4directions( int[][] a, int i, int j, boolean[][] visited ) {
        if ( i < 0 || j < 0 || i == a.length || j == a[0].length )
            return 0;

        if ( i == a.length - 1 && j == a[0].length - 1 )
            return 1;

        if ( visited[i][i] == true )
            return 0;

        visited[i][j] = true;

        int right = findWays4directions( a, i, j + 1, visited );
        int down = findWays4directions( a, i + 1, j, visited );
        int left = findWays4directions( a, i, j - 1, visited );
        int up = findWays4directions( a, i - 1, j, visited );

        return left + down + right + up;
    }
```

How can I count all paths from source to destination in a matrix moving in all 4 directions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `visited[i][j] = false` when exiting a cell. But beware: this is not a dynamic programming solution (I'm convinced that there is no DP solution to this problem). Instead, you're doing an unbounded search (a kind of backtracking):

Also: fixed the bug `if (visited[i][i]) ...` in your code.

```
static int findWays4directions( int[][] a, int i, int j, boolean[][] visited ) {
    if ( i < 0 || j < 0 || i == a.length || j == a[0].length )
        return 0;

    if ( i == a.length - 1 && j == a[0].length - 1 )
        return 1;

    if ( visited[i][j] == true )
        return 0;

    visited[i][j] = true;

    int right = findWays4directions( a, i, j + 1, visited );
    int down = findWays4directions( a, i + 1, j, visited );
    int left = findWays4directions( a, i, j - 1, visited );
    int up = findWays4directions( a, i - 1, j, visited );

    visited[i][j] = false;

    return left + down + right + up;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you setting visited[i][j] = false; because, for the next path, you want a[i][j] to be allowed ? Also, can we do a chat, please?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the dfs algorithm, however the base case check need add `visited[i][j]` to check the duplicated visit.

```
if (i < 0 || i >= n || j < 0 || j >= n || visited[i][j]) {
            return 0;
}
```